# Slow response time in IIS when load test

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I host a Asp.Net site in a IIS. It has only one single page called Service.aspx. All request goes to the page, processed by C# code, then return a json format response.(Actually it is a API, not a web page)
  Everything goes well when tested by very little users. The average response time is about 80~100ms. But when I used a load test of 200 users against the website. the response time is up to about 1~2s.
  Everything seems normal in Asp.Net tracing. Requests only takes 50 ~ 100 ms.

But in the IIS's log. The average request time to this page is 1000 to 2000ms. Why it is so slow? What happens when many user connect to the website?
  If the latency happens in the logic code of the page, surely I can optimize it. But my log clearly shows most time is spent in IIS. Any idea?

Comment: Create a proper web service using web API or WCF. Returning JSON from a web forms .aspx page is a hack and you are running the entire asp.net lifecycle for no good reason.

Comment: Agreed with Ben, however you should also check to see how many worker processes your IIS is configured to spin up? When are they recycle? Did you turn Debug off in your web.config. Is it using Classic pipeline?

Comment: Thank Ben and Tien. For some reasons, I need the current framework(aspx) to host my API. So I need to find out which part is most time consuming. Is there any way to log time for each part of life cycle in IIS?